# query user objectIDs stored in an array swift

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to make groups of users in a class that will queried to form a group chat. I have stored the objectId's of each user in the group in an array. Then I save the array to Parse.

I am having trouble figuring out how to query the array, and then compare the objectID's with the _User class so the group members can be identified by name and profile picture.

Right now this is the code I have, but I know that it isn't the right method. Does anyone have any advice? Thanks!

```
class squadDetailInformation: UIViewController{

    var currentObject: PFObject?
    var squadmemberstrial: NSArray = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let object = currentObject{

            squadmemberstrial = (object.objectForKey("SquadMembers") as? NSArray)!

            let user : PFUser = object.objectForKey("objectID") as! PFUser

            let queryUsers = PFUser.query()
            queryUsers.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(user.objectId, block: {
                (userGet :PFObject!,error : NSError!) -> Void in
            })

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an array of object ids. An array of proper pointers would be better, but still isn't ideal. Instead you should use a relationship as you can directly query it and you can also use the relationship query in other queries as a filter.

Comment: I'm a little confused about relationships, can I set one up between an object in a class and several users?

Comment: Your class, whatever it's called, has a relationship to `User`, and you can add any number of `User` instances to that relationship (on an instance of that class) and then query for them